# Collection Reuseable View not showing UILabel and UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a problem with my UICollectionView.

I added a header of 50 to my collection view so I could add a UILabel and a UITextField at the top. The problem is it doesn't show up when I run the code:

**My Storyboard:**

[image]

**What happens in ios simulator:**

[image]

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: remove your search label and text field from reusable collection view and call the label and text field in view controller

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I don't have a view controller. I have a uicollectionview controller. Look at my storyboard. Would I need to have a uiviewcontroller instead. If so, then would I have to call the uicollectionview delegates in the .h file?

Comment: no no , just change the frame of your collection view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

try this sequence of create the collection view

Comment: its not allowing me to change the location of the UILabel.

Comment: varun konjam nalla parunga ungaloda ? la irukira screen shot kum , enoda answer la screen shot kum ena variation ,

Answer (score 0):

Put this into your `collectionView.m` file.

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[Your header cocoa file] *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"ObjectCVHeader" forIndexPath:indexPath];
return headerView;
}
```

// You need to create a set of .h.m file of `UICollectionReusableView`. After that link them with your header view.